# Getting Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0."

Tags: ios, api, swift4, alamofire

I am facing a very strange issue while calling APIs,

When I call API first time, I am getting below error,

> FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

and in failure block, I again call the same API and I got the proper response.

I have used Alamofire for API Calls.

I tried very hard to figure out the solution but no luck yet.

Below is my code,

```
Alamofire.request(URL(string: baseURL + url.rawValue)!, method: method, parameters: param, encoding: encoding, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    print(response)
    let responseJson = JSON(response.result.value as Any)
    if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
    {
        print(statusCode)
        let status = accepTableStatusCodes.contains(statusCode)
        switch status {

            case true:
               success(responseJson)
               break
            default:
                if let message = responseJson.dictionaryObject?[ApiKeys.message] as? String{

                    if message != ApiKeys.Unauthorized {
                        DELEGATE.window!.rootViewController?.view.showToast(toastMessage: message, duration: 0.3)
                    }

                }
                failure(responseJson)
                break
         }
    } else {
            print("Something went wrong")
    }
}
```

I have tried by changing responseJSON to responseString. Nothing is working.

In header I am passing below values,

```
header = [ApiKeys.Authorization : "Bearer \(user.token ?? "")", "Accept" : "application/json","Content-Type": "application/json"]
```

I don't understand why it is throwing an error on the first call and the same call gives a proper response in the second call. In my project, I have integrated almost 10+ APIs and in each API, this same thing is happening.
Really weird and strange behavior! :(

Comment: The error simply says that the received data is not JSON, it's most likely HTML. Check it by making a `String` from the `Data` and print it.

Comment: I understood, but the same code is giving a response if I callback the same API in the failure block. @vadian
If every time it gives JSON error, then I can tell backend person to look into it. But this is something unexpected behavior I am facing.

Comment: As I said insert the line `print(String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8)!)` and see what you get

Comment: @vadian If I print above statement then I am getting below response,

<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>

Comment: As I suspected it's HTML, so the issue is related to the request, not to the response.

Comment: @vadian Yes, the response string says that it's a bad request issue. So again my question is the same. I am calling the same API with the same request parameters in the failure block, then I am getting success response. Sorry, I know this is weird but this is what I am facing. :(